# Command failed with exit code 1: next build - Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, deployment, netlify

I'm trying to deploy my site to Netlify and I keep getting this error. My site was working and was able to build before this build. Any ideas on what I can do? Also, I'm using Next.JS for the site.

```
3:43:14 PM: - info Generating static pages (2/6)
3:43:14 PM: - info Generating static pages (4/6)
3:43:14 PM: - info Generating static pages (6/6)
3:43:14 PM: > Export encountered errors on following paths:
3:43:14 PM:     /account/page: /account
3:43:14 PM: ​
3:43:14 PM: build.command failed                                        
3:43:14 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:43:14 PM: ​
3:43:14 PM:   Error message
3:43:14 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: next build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
3:43:14 PM: ​
3:43:14 PM:   Error location
3:43:14 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
3:43:14 PM:   next build
3:43:14 PM: ​
3:43:14 PM:   Resolved config
3:43:14 PM:   build:
3:43:14 PM:     command: next build
3:43:14 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
3:43:14 PM:     environment:
3:43:14 PM:       - NEXT_PRIVATE_TARGET
3:43:14 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/.next
3:43:14 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
3:43:14 PM:   plugins:
3:43:14 PM:     - inputs: {}
3:43:14 PM:       origin: ui
3:43:14 PM:       package: '@netlify/plugin-nextjs'
3:43:16 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
3:43:16 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
3:43:17 PM: Finished processing build request in 43.454s
```

I've tried reuploading the site and adding "CI= npm run build" in my build and deploy settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Select your site from `Netlify`. Go to the specific site's `Site configuration`. Click `Environment Variables`. Create two new environment variables:

1. `Key: NODE_VERSION`, `Value: v14.17.0`
2. `Key: NPM_VERSION`, `Value: 9.3.0`

/* *Specify the value of the version that is used in your project* */

The day you deployed the site for the first time, the version of npm or node might be different from what it is now. Try updating the node and npm versions, and deploy the site again. This might fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can try these steps to solve issue;

**Inspect the problematic page:** The error seems to be coming from /account/page: /account. Make sure everything is in order with that page file.

**Try a local build:** Run next build on your local machine. If it fails, the error message might give you more insight.

**Review your data fetching:** If you're using getStaticProps or getServerSideProps, ensure they're working as expected.

**Look at your next.config.js:** If you have this file, double-check it's configured correctly.

**Verify your environment variables:** You're using NEXT_PRIVATE_TARGET. Make sure it's set correctly in your Netlify settings.

**Update Next.js and Netlify plugin:** If you're not on the latest versions, consider upgrading.